# Attendance and custom field tracker

Tags: civievent

My question is could I use civicrm and Drupal for this.

There is a sign up form for students, I have attached an image, all fields would not be used, this is just an example.

There are an estimate of 10 students.

Daily attendance needs to be tracked (Present or Absent) and the date. Would also be nice to add a custom field to be able to track....let's say points for good behavior.

So daily, someone can input if john was present or absent for a particular day and how many points for "good behavior".

A search so someone can see how many students were present on a certain day, or how many females attended and how many points they received for good behavior on a particular month or day.
[image]

Comment: This is possible with standard CiviCRM and it's custom data feature. But would this be a satisfying answer?

Comment: Thank you for the responses @Sanjay Jain and petednz - fuzion. After reading the responses to my question. Seems like I need more know how in civicrm. The answers seem simple, but executing them, there are a lot more steps to be done regarding the first answer. Creating a custom field requires first creating a custom field set. Setting up a profile is similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up custom fields for each day's attendance and points. Then set up a profile using those fields

An admin user can then search for the participants, select all, Action > Batch update via profile.

If the students attend multiple similar events, the custom field for each day would be unique, eg Attendance 3/15. Otherwise you could use Attendance Day 1.

You should be able to advance search (or search builder) for the custom fields to see the results you want.

If this is something that is going to take a lot of admin time, you should consider a customized solution (extension).

Note: The question was sent to me directly and I asked him to post here on SE, in case others have a better solution and/or my option helps others.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay - i have posted as as separate answer but agree that Activity is the way to go, and that for a small institution the basic approach you outline should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

We have done something for an education provider that tracked Attendance. In our case they wanted to have summary reports for each week. Therefore we made an Activity with 10 fields representing Mon am, Mon pm, Tue am, etc

Each week an Activity is added in bulk to each Student (via Adv Search).

We then provide a link to 'this weeks attendance' which takes users to a customised Report that allows the staff to mark the attendance for all their students on a single page - ie the Report is 'inline editable'. This refinement was provided because of the large number of students involved.

I hope the initial suggestion of using Activities is helpful. Unfortunately the Views summaries and the Report functionality are quite specific to the client so cannot be easily shared. But I am adding a screenshot of the inline editor for the Report in case it looks useful enough and in case you or anyone who comes along can fund it becoming an extension.

[image]